# Why does Outlook revert my change to a meeting and claim it is "out of date"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

For an upcoming meeting I am organizing, someone else set up an Outlook calendar entry and sent it to me in order to suggest a date and to make sure I do not forget organizing the meeting.

I would like to move the meeting now, and did so yesterday (by shifting it forward by a week), which seemed to have worked. Today, I am surprised to find Outlook has moved back my meeting to its original date and time, and it sent me an automated message saying "Your meeting was found to be out of date and has been automatically updated."

**What has happened here and what does "out of date" mean?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the owner of the calendar entry, I think when you move it in your calendar, this change is overwritten when it syncs with the original entry from your colleague.  As their's in the master version, yours is considered out of sync (or out of date) with that version.

If you want to move the meeting, you could propose a new time. Right click on the calendar entry and select "propose new time". Then you can send a message to the owner, and it will update for everyone who has that entry.

Comment: Good find. I suppose this is one of the situations where the use cases discussed by the software designers do not always match up with how real life works ;) (In this case: me: "I'm going to give you a brief crash course on <library XYZ> for you guys." - one of the people addressed: "Ok, I'll create a calendar event with a possible timeslot right away and send it to you so you don't forget; feel free to adapt the timeslot as you like.")